# Möller-Trumbore Ray-Tri Intersection Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, raycasting, glm-math

**I have implemented Möller-Trumbore Ray-Tri Intersection Algorithm as follows;**

Note: I used GLM for vec3 - dot - cross - sub . . .

```
    bool intersect_triangle( vec3 &O, vec3& D, vec3 &vert0, vec3 &vert1, vec3 &vert2, vec3 & P, bool cull )
{
    static const float eps = 0.000001;
    vec3 edge1( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    vec3 edge2( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    vec3 tvec( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    vec3 pvec( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    vec3 qvec( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    float det, inv_det;

    edge1 = vert1 - vert0;
    edge2 = vert2 - vert0;
    pvec = cross( D, edge2 );
    det = dot( edge1, pvec );

    if( cull )
    {
        if( det < eps )
        {
            cout << "cull test failed" << endl;
            return false;
        }

        tvec = O - vert0;

        P.x = dot( tvec, pvec );

        if( P.x < 0.0f || P.x > det )
        {
            cout << "U test failed" << endl;
            return false;
        }

        qvec = cross( tvec, edge1 );
        P.y = dot( D, qvec );

        if( P.y < 0.0f || ( P.x + P.y ) > det )
        {
            cout << "V test failed" << endl;
            return false;
        }

        P.z = dot( edge2, qvec );
        inv_det = 1.0f / det;
        P.x *= inv_det;
        P.y *= inv_det;
        P.z *= inv_det;
    }
    else
    {
        if( det > - eps && det < eps )
        {
            return false;
        }

        inv_det = 1.0f / det;
        tvec = O - vert0;
        P.x = dot( tvec, pvec ) * inv_det;

        if( P.x < 0.0f || P.x > 1.0f )
        {
            return false;
        }

        qvec = cross( tvec, edge1 );
        P.y = dot( D, qvec ) * inv_det;

        if( P.y < 0.0f || P.x + P.y > 1.0f )
        {
            return false;
        }

        P.z = dot( edge2, qvec ) * inv_det;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**And I`m using the implementation as follows;**

```
        for( size_t i = 0; i < tris.size(); i++ )
        {
            mat4 mvp_inverse = inverse( tris[i]->_mvp );
            vec4 origin = mvp_inverse * vec4(
                              ( _lastEvent.motion.x - _width / 2.0f ) / _width / 2.0f, ( _height / 2.0f - _lastEvent.motion.y ) / _height / 2.0f, -1, 1 );
            vec4 dir = mvp_inverse * vec4( 0, 0, 1, 0 );
            vec3 O = vec3( origin.x, origin.y, origin.z );
            vec3 D = normalize( vec3( dir.x, dir.y, dir.z ) );
            vec3 P;

            for( size_t j = 0; j < tris[i]->_indices.size(); j += 3 )
            {
                bool intersection = intersect_triangle( O, D,
                                                        tris[i]->_vertices[tris[i]->_indices[j]],
                                                        tris[i]->_vertices[tris[i]->_indices[j + 1]],
                                                        tris[i]->_vertices[tris[i]->_indices[j + 2]],
                                                        P, true );

                if( intersection )
                {
                    cout << P.x << " " << P.y << " " << P.z << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "no intersection" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

**The implementation works at some places. It detects correctly when the cursor is pointing inside of tri. It does not work in some places where outside of tri.
I do not know why ? I have used "Fast, Minimum Storage Ray/Triangle Intersection" paper to implement.**

**Test Screenshoots;**

Screenshoot 1:
[image: Screenshoot 1]

Screenshoot 2
[image: Screenshoot 2]

Comment: Does it not detect correctly only at edge boundaries or corners, or elsewhere too?

Comment: elsewhere... usually right - up side of tri. look the screenshoot 1 for right-up side.

Comment: There're some things you need to know before implementing an intersection testing algorithm. There're fundamental to 3D graphics programming anyways. Are the points fed in a cwise or ccwise order? If yes, where would the direction that the normal vector be pointing? What handedness is your coordinate system? The numbers you get out of a cross product depends on this. More specifically, have a mathematical/intuitive understanding of this algorithm and then implement it, it'd be easy to debug. Without these, we'd not be able to help you; for instance, what do the variables `D`, `O`, `P` mean?

Comment: which points ? vertices are ordered in ccwise . D normal is cwise .
D = direction of ray
O = origin of ray
P = intersection point

Comment: The intersection test itself looks OK to me, but your code to calculate the ray coordinates seems wrong (at least for perspective projections). You can;t ignore the resulting `w` coordinate, but have to do the perspective divide to get a useful origin. For the direction, I'm not sure if this will work at all this way. The perspective projection will transform infinitely far away points (which conceptually are directions with `w`=0) to some _finite_ points, so I'm not really sure what the inverse will do. You could use two points, one with z=-1, and one with z=1, unproject these to build ray.

Comment: Calculation of ray coordinates referenced from CodeProject;

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/625787/Pick-Selection-with-OpenGL-and-OpenCL

Comment: @derhass thank you for suggestion. i will try as soon as

Comment: @derhass you are right :) I solved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is constructing ray origin and direction**

**Solution:**

```
            vec4 viewport( 0.0f, 0.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f );

            vec3 unProjectedNear = unProject( vec3( _lastEvent.motion.x, 600 - _lastEvent.motion.y, -1.0f ),  _view * tris[i]->_model, _proj, viewport );
            vec3 unProjectedFar = unProject( vec3( _lastEvent.motion.x, 600 - _lastEvent.motion.y, +1.0f ),  _view * tris[i]->_model, _proj, viewport );
            vec3 D = normalize(unProjectedFar-unProjectedNear);
            vec3 O = unProjectedNear;
```